# Geany parsing to extract symbol infomration

Tags: geany

I want to alter Geany configuration to change how markdown is parsed:

1. Sidebar Symbols list only displays headings 2 and 3
2. fold points for headings 2 and 3

The Geany documentation hints that it can be done:

> "supported filetypes are parsed to extract the symbol information (aka workspace symbols)." [Geany Manual, 2021](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#id78)

How does Geany parse files?

1. language keywords, are editable via Tools > configuration Editor > FileTypes configuration
2. Pattern matching *File* for functions, **how?**
3. Pattern matching files in *Project* folder for functions, **how?**
4. ... are there **others?**